# Анимация одного UI объекта при клике по другому (Unity)

Tags: unity3d

Есть два UI объекта: `button` и `panel`. При старте сцены `panel имеет масштабирование

```
panel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

При клике по `button` должна запускаться анимация масштабирования `panel`

примерно так:

```
float speed = 1;
 while (panel.transform.localScale.x < 1)
    {
        panel.transform.localScale += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
```

все это в методе `public void OpenPanel()`

При таком варианте панель при клике по кнопке появляется, но без анимации масштабирования. В чем неправа, подскажите?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ваш "скейл" панели вы делаете за один кадр. Т.е. рисуется ваша панель со скейлом 0. Потом вы нажимаете кнопку, в цикле while прокручивается вся логика, которая устанавливает скейл в 1, после чего метод заканчивается и начинает рисоваться следующий кадр, где скейл панели уже 1(а точнее чуть больше, т.к. вы просто делаете +=)

Самый простой способ сделать то, что вам нужно - использовать корутины. Так же советую использовать для изменения значения `Mathf.MoveTowards(current, target, value)` сдвигает значение current к target не больше чем на value, однако и не даёт результату быть больше, чем target. Так ваш скейл всегда будет 1 или 0, и не вылезет в отрицательные значения или больше 1. Общий метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
    //Соответственно методы открытия и закрытия просто передают нужный параметр в 
    //метод и запускают его результат, как корутину. Вместо `0.4f` можете использовать 
    //переменную из класса.
    public void OpenPanel() => StartCoroutine(ScaleRoutine(1, 0.4f)); 

    public void ClosePanel() => StartCoroutine(ScaleRoutine(0, 0.4f));

    IEnumerator ScaleRoutine(float target, float duration)
    {
        float secondStep = Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x - target) / duration; //считаем на сколько нужно сдвигать значение каждую секунду, чтобы уложить изменение в длительность
        float current = transform.localScale.x;
        while (current < target)
        {
            current = Mathf.MoveTowards(current, target, Time.deltaTime * secondStep); 
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(current, current, current);
            yield return null; ///это заставит корутину дождаться следующего кадра, прежде чем продолжить вызов
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду изучать. Все же хочу уточнить, а почему, к примеру, нельзя как-то напрямую обратиться к методу update объекта panel, чтобы вызвать его трансформацию? К примеру, я записываю в метод update panel трансформацию, но она срабатывает только при определенном условии, а это условие как-то получается извне (передается переменной?). Скрипт прикрепляю к panel, остальная логика в другом скрипте... ну или что-то подобное

Comment: @Volha, не совсем понимаю ваш вопрос) ваша проблема была в том, что вы за один кадр делали операцию, которая должна была отрабатывать несколько кадров. В итоге вы не видели промежуточных состояний, т.к. отрисовка кадров между ними не происходила и вы сразу видели финал. В Unity, при стандартных условиях все происходит строго друг за другом, в том числе и изменение изображения на экране. Пока все ваши методы не закончат работу новый кадр рисоваться не будет. Поэтому я показал вам пример через корутину, где пропуск кадра посреди метода вызывается принудительно.

Comment: нет, это я поняла, я поняла, что моя ошибка была в том, что все отрисовывалось за один кадр. Я о другом. К примеру, у panel (если добавить соотв.скрипт), есть метод update(). Если мой код анимации добавить в него, то анимация реализуется так, как мне нужно. Другой вопрос, что она начнется сразу после старта scene, а мне нужно, чтобы она началась по событию, получаемому из другого скрипта... к примеру в виде переменной. Ваша реализация понятна, но вот такая реализация (запуск анимации в методе update при событии) она возможна?

Comment: @Volha, да, возможна. В Update добавляете проверку условия, если условие не выполняется - логику анимации не воспроизводите. Методом OpenPanel делаете так, чтобы условие выполнялось. Когда панель полностью открылась снова делаете так, чтобы условие не выполнялось. Проблема этой реализации в том, что она постоянно крутит метод Update и в каждом кадре вы делаете проверку, которая, по сути, вам не нужна. При этом панель вам не только открывать, но и закрывать нужно. Значит логика в Update() станет ещё сложнее.

Comment: @ M. Green, спасибо большое, вы решили мой вопрос, а также я подтянула знания о том, как происходит отрисовка анимаций в unity ))). В итоге реализовала метод в том же скрипте, что и остальные методы. Скрипт прикреплен к canvas, который обрабатывает клик по кнопке, в результате которой стартует трансформация panel. Короче, создала переменную bool onclick, в метод клика записала onClick =! onClick. И уже в методе update () (получается, что самого канваса, т.к. скрипт висит на нем) прописала трансформацию панели:

Comment: `if (onClick == true)
        {
            float speed = 1f;
            if (downloadPanel.transform.localScale.x > 1) return;
            downloadPanel.transform.localScale += new Vector3(1 * Time.deltaTime * speed, 1 * Time.deltaTime * speed, 0);
        }`

Comment: Предложенный Вами вариант тоже буду изучать, т.к., как вы пишите, он не будет постоянно крутить метод update(). Спасибо!

Comment: @Volha, при проверке буловых переменных можно не использовать сравнение со значением. т.е. `if(onClick == true)` и `if(onClick)` равнозначны. Вместо `if(onClick == false)` или `if(onClick != true)` можно использовать `if(!onClick)`. И в целом, старайтесь избегать использования метода `Update()` это всегда лучше с точки зрения производительности.

Comment: @Volha, то, что я вам рассказал про отрисовку касается не только анимаций - вся игра рисуется последовательно и покадрово. Если интересно откройте окно `Window->Analysis->Frame Debuger` и после запуска игры, нажмите в нем кнопку Enable. Это поставить игру на паузу и вы сможете подробно посмотреть процесс графической отрисовки кадра. Чем меньше этапов у вас будет во время отрисовки - тем лучше, т.к. видео процессор будет меньше нагружаться.

Comment: @ M. Green, не хочу показаться назойливой))) Просто стала изучать дальше материал, и наткнулась на еще одно решение проблемы. К примеру, я создаю скрипт, ну типа AppearanceAnim, в методе update() пишу трансформацию увеличения, прикрепляю этот скрипт к panel, но делаю его неактивным. В другом (основном) скрипте я делаю его активным, когда это необходимо, и деактивирую после выполнения трансформации. Критика?

Comment: хочу дополнить, я хотела сделать акцент на том, что раз скрипт после выполнения задачи отключается, то и метод update не будет крутиться постоянно

Comment: @Volha, да, такой вариант тоже приемлем. Но если этим скриптом вы не только открывать, но и закрывать хотите всё равно придётся использовать методы в классе, а не только `.enable`. К тому же, все обращения к полям и методам от Unity происходят внутри движка. Т.е. если вы хотите выключить объект, лучше повесьте на него свой скрипт, который будет делать это, т.к. в противном случае через месяц вы будете очень долго искать кто же выключает ваш объект) ведь вызовы внутренних методов Unity снаружи не отследить.

Comment: @ M. Green, в методе update AppearanceAnim после выполнения трансформации дополнила  enabled = false; Т.е. получается, что скрипт отключает сам себя после выполнения анимации. А включается он уже из другого класса (в случае необходимости). Очень, кстати, неплохой для меня вариант, т.к. у меня много UI объектов должны появляться или исчезать. Получается, достаточно создать 2 файла анимации, нацепить на все объекты, деактивировать, и, в случае, необходимости, их активировать. Ну а отключаются они сами. Как-то так)

Comment: @Volha, правильнее будет не включать снаружи, через `.enable`, а вызывать метод, который включит скрипт изнутри) чтобы реализация была одинакова и никто не управлял состоянием скрипта снаружи.

Comment: @ M. Green, точно, инкапсуляция, совсем забыла))) Переделала, спасибо еще раз!